# WordPress Contact Form 7 - Validation and pulling through information

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a couple of questions regarding Contact Form 7.

I am trying to pull through the pages title into the email, but after some research I found that:

> Note that the [*post**] tag has value only when you put the contact form into content of a post or a page. They are not available if the contact form is put inside a sidebar widget.

http://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/

The way my site works, the contact form is embedded into the html as a lightbox, and can't be moved.

Is there a way it is possible to still get the information, another way around this?

The second part of my question is validation:
I found this link from Contact Form 7 - http://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/

Which explains some custom validation.

My question is, does anyone have any way of validating a postcode? as long as it is a postcode, then the form may submit?

EDIT:
I found this code, which supposingly checks if the postcode is in a certain area, not too sure if this could really help?

```
    add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text','postcode_custom_filter', 10, 2); // Email field
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'postcode_custom_filter', 10, 2); // Req. Email field
// Add custom validation for CF7 form fields on postcode

function postcode_in_area($postcode){ // check if the postcode is in our area
    if(
        preg_match('2010', $postcode) ||
        preg_match('2011', $postcode) ||
        preg_match('2013', $postcode) ||
        preg_match('2014', $postcode) ||
        preg_match('2015', $postcode) ||
        preg_match('2016', $postcode) ||
        preg_match('2017', $postcode) ||
        preg_match('2018', $postcode) ||
        preg_match('2019', $postcode)
    ){
        return true; // It's an area we operate in
    }else{
        return false; // It's an area we do NOT service
    }
}

function postcode_custom_filter($result,$tag){
    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if('postcode' == $type){ // Only apply to fields with the form field name of "Your-Postcode"
        $the_value = $_POST[$name];
        if( postcode_in_area($the_value)){ // Isn't a company email address (it matched the list of free email providers)
            $result['valid'] = false;
            $result['reason'][$name] = "sorry we do not operate in this area";
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and also this?
http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/uk-postcode-validation-function-php

Comment: you need to try something and then ask for help, there would be quite a few ways of approaching this dependant on your theme, knowledge etc.

Comment: I have no clue where to even start on either, any useful links would be awesome, really need to get this working

Comment: Do you have any piece of code to show us? It's really important for your first question, we will be able to help you so. For your second question, we need more information too, for exemple, in which country is your postcode supposed to be? You have nearly find the whole answer with your link, but we, again, need more informations.

Comment: The postcode would be in the UK. I will edit OP to some examples I found

Comment: OP edited, hopefully this is a start. Can't think of any way to do this

Comment: to get the page (or close enough to it) just save `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` into a variable (escape it etc...) and hook into the form processing script (not sure of contact form 7, but there more than likely is one) you can add in your script to check postcode as well. but that could also be done with js..